# Yet Again and Again, Another Riley Riddle

Tags: riddle

> My prefix is angry.
>
> My suffix is too.
>
> My infix is a name.
>
> Without me, life is lame.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are

> DANGER

*My prefix is angry*

> DANG!

*My suffix is too*

> ANGER

*My infix is a name*

> ANG (like ANG LEE)

*Without me, life is lame*

> Live dangerously!

Comment: Very good ^^ ---